# How to recover admin password in websphere portal v7?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I have forgotten the password to enter the websphere portal as admin.How to recover the password?..PLease help in this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How to encode your password in Websphere 6 or 7

Step 1: Open up your console and navigate to the folder that contains "ws_runtime.jar". 
Use a search tool to find it.

Step 2: java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordEncoder "password"

Example:

*Input*

```
java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordEncoder "password"
```

*Output*

```
decoded password == "password", encoded password == "{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs="
```

### How to decode your password in Websphere 6 or 7

Step 1: Location and open "security.xml". It will be folder with a similar path like so "runtime\..?..\PROFILE_ACCOUNT\...?..\workspace\..?..\". 
Use a search tool to find it.

Step 2: In "security.xml", find the "authDataEntries" tag and then get the password attribute.

Step 3: Open up your console and navigate to the folder that contains "ws_runtime.jar". 
Use a search tool to find it.

Step 4: java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordDecoder PASSWORD_ATTIBUTE

Example:

*Input*

```
java -cp ws_runtime.jar com.ibm.ws.security.util.PasswordDecoder {xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs=
```

*Output*

```
encoded password == "{xor}Lz4sLCgwLTs=", decoded password == "password"
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following technote:

[Forgot password and cannot access WebSphere Application Server administrative console](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405302)

Answer (score 0):

[How to reset the administrator's password in the file registry](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392427). May be you can try this.